# TypeScript errors when I move switch statement cases to own functions?

Tags: typescript, redux

Im using TypeScript with Redux. This code works fine:

```
export type action =
  | {
      type: "do-other-thing";
      name: string;
    }
  | {
      type: "do-something";
      index: number;
    };

function reducer(state: state = initState, action: action): state {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "do-something":
        if (action.index === 0) return state;
        // More logic
    case "do-other-thing":
        // More logic
    default:
        return state;
  }
```

However I want to move the return cases from the switch statement to be their own functions:

```
function doSomething(state: state, action : action): state {
    if (action.index === 0) return state;
    // more logic
}

function reducer(state: state = initState, action: action): state {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "do-something":
        return doSomething(state, action);
    case "do-other-thing":
        // More logic
    default:
        return state;
  }
```

Now the `doSomething` function has a TypeScript error:

> Property 'index' does not exist on type 'action'.   Property 'index'
>   does not exist on type '{ type: "do-something"; width: number;
>   isLandscape: boolean; }'.ts(2339)

I can see that TypeScript isn't aware that due to the switch statement the `action` object will have and `index` property. Is there a way to make it aware of this?

Comment: How could Typescript possibly know? You're defining the function outside of the switch statement, Typescript can't know the only place you're using the function is inside the case block.

Comment: I know that we'd need to explicitly define the type for `action`, but why would an ideal TypeScript compiler not possibly know when it's used in only exactly one place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you defined the parameter as `action` on the `doSomething` function, this allows anyone to pass any `action` in other places. You most likely want to actually define it to be a more restricted type like this:

```
type DoOtherThingAction = { type: "do-other-thing"; name: string; };
type DoSomeThingAction = { type: "do-something"; index: number; };
export type action = 
  | DoOtherThingAction
  | DoSomeThingAction;
```

and then:

```
function doSomething(state: state, action : DoSomeThingAction): state {
    if (action.index === 0) return state;
    // more logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `doSomething` doesnt work with all actions but with action with `index` property, I would split some typying in order to be able to more clear type the demand:

```
type A = {
      type: "do-other-thing";
      name: string;
    };
type B = {
      type: "do-something";
      index: number;
    };
type Action = A | B

function doSomething(state: state, action: B): state {
    if (action.index === 0) return state;
    // more logic
}
```

Now `doSomething` works only with variant `B` of your `Action` type.